# Multiplication in homology for non-positively curved Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

Let $M$ be a complete, path-connected Riemannian manifold with negative Gaussian  curvature. Then for any two points on $M$, there exists a unique geodesic connecting them. (Am I missing hypotheses here? I read Do Carmo's book ten years ago, so I'm rusty.) This gives rise to a smooth map
$$
M\times M \to M
$$
by sending $(x,y)$ to the midpoint of the unique geodesic connecting them.

(Bear with me, I haven't thought about this stuff in a long time.) Does this define a multiplication at the level of homology? If so, can we say anything interesting about it?

Comment: I think you're missing simply connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hypotheses are not enough to guarantee existence and uniqueness of geodesics connecting any two points. First, unless you're only interested in the $2$-dimensional case, you need to use *sectional curvature*, not Gaussian curvature. Second, even with negative sectional curvature, you won't have uniqueness of geodesics unless $M$ is simply connected.

Then the problem is that a simply connected manifold with a complete metric of negative curvature (or even just nonpositive curvature) is diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$ by the Cartan-Hadamard theorem, so its only nontrivial homology group is $H_0(M)\cong \mathbb Z$, and $H_0(M\times M)\cong \mathbb Z$ as well. The induced homomorphism from $H_0(M\times M)$ to $H_0(M)$ given by your recipe is essentially the identity map.